# Selenium can't find geckodriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

I tried to control firefox with selenium by using geckodriver. The script can't find geckodriver as it said "Message 'geckodriver" executable needs to be in PATH". As I already put geckodriver into /usr/local/bin.

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MacOS I strongly recommend using brew. After installing it with brew never had any problems, could use it with selenium easily.

```
brew install geckodriver
```

http://brewformulas.org/geckodriver should help :)

Comment: I am using linux.

Answer (score 0):

Phoo, finally I found the solution. According to mantonel. 2016. Web scraping with a Raspberry Pi and Python. [ONLINE] Available at: http://www.mantonel.com/tutorials/web-scraping-raspberry-pi-and-python. [Accessed 6 May 2018], 
the selenium 3.0.1 doesn't work with Firefox 45.4.0.

It works, after I installed selenium version 2.53.5 (pip3 install selenium==2.53.5)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure you're running on the latest version of selenium and have the latest release of geckodriver.

   - Update selenium using pip:

     `pip install -U selenium`
   - Download geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2. Extract the geckodriver executable and place it in the Scripts folder of the python installations. It should be in this directory
   Drive:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3x\Scripts
3. Now simply import and call the driver

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   myBrowser = webdriver.Firefox()
   ```